# Parsing chrome version from user agent

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, user-agent

I need to find the version of Chrome using PHP.

I coded this:

```
$ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.60 Safari/537.1";
preg_match( "#Chrome/([0-9]{2})#", $ua, $match );
print_r($match);
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Chrome/21
    [1] => 21
)
```

I have two questions:

Will this work on all chrome browsers? (because the $ua is my own user agent.

Also how can I make the pattern so it returns only "21" instead of "Chrome/21" and "21" in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *WON'T* work on all Chrome browsers. What if it's Chrome Version 3? Or Chrome Version 2245?

See [me](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/).

What I would do is change your Regular Expression to the following:

```
preg_match( "#Chrome/(.+?)\.#", $ua, $match );
```

This returns the same thing as what you have now, but it also works with any-digit versions.

```
array (
  0 => 'Chrome/21.',
  1 => '21',
)
```

You can test this [here](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html).

**As for your second question,** you cannot modify `preg_match()` to return the value like that. Simply setting `$match = $match[1]` works fine, though, and is completely acceptable!

Comment: what if I want all numbers ? In this case: `21.0.1180.60`

Answer (score -1):

1. As long as chrome doesn't change their UA, you will be fine.
2. Add:

   $match = $match[1];